# One PDO function for any query

Tags: php, pdo

I am looking to create a php function to make SQL queries.  I would supply the sql query (insert, update, delete, select, replace) and any placeholders, then it would return an array with the values or errors detailing the issue.

here is what i have so far, it works ok, but I would like to know if there is a way to make it better, or if I have any errors that I dont see my self.

```
 $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $passwd);
 $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
 $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

function sql_query($query, $placeholders = false){
  $data = array();
  global $pdo;
  $letter = substr($query, 0, 1);

  try{
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    //echo "Successfully Prepared<br/>";
  }
  catch(PDOException $e){
    $data['error'] = "Prepare Failed: ".$e->getMessage();
    return $data;
  }

  if(!$stmt){
    $data['error'] = "Query Failed";
    return $data;
  }

  try{
    if($placeholders){
    $stmt->execute($placeholders);
  }
  else{
    $stmt->execute();
  }

  $data['count'] = $stmt->rowCount();

  if($letter === "S"){
  if($data['count'] > 1){
    $data['result'] = $stmt->fetchAll();
  }else{
    $data['result'][] = $stmt->fetch();
  }
 }    
}
catch(PDOException $e){
 $data['error'] = 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}  
return $data;
}
```

Comment: I recommend you create different functions for select, insert, update and delete.

Comment: The idea was to build a single function that I can give it a sql string and return either result array or error array.